# Деепричастный оборот, пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот

Спишите, расставляя() где нужно, знаки препинания. - "где нужно" входит в деепричастный оборот? Если нет, то чем тогда является "где нужно" и нужна ли запятая на месте скобок?

Comment: Спишите, расставляя() где нужно() знаки препинания. - Вторые скобки забыл.

Comment: если не секрет, поделитесь, из какого учебника вы свои вопросы берете - и/или зачем они вам нужны. Понимаете, помогать человеку, которому это нужно по работе - одно. Разбираться в темах курсовых и дипломах или так публикации готовить - другое. Ну а развлекать досужих граждан - совсем третье. У вас вопросы явно на близкие темы, но какие очень уж противоестественные для насущных надобностей.

Comment: @behemothus, мне просто интересны трудные для меня случаи русского языка. Могу делать задание, читать книгу или газету, общаться в интернете и увидеть пример написания, который я не могу еще объяснить или соотнести с какими-либо правилами. Так я немного изучаю русский язык. Но это сложно, так как в нем многое взаимосвязано. Я пытаюсь разобраться в вопросе до конца, узнаю что-то новое, но при этом расширяется и область моего незнания.

Answer (score 3):

Вот обычное задание в учебнике для 5-го класса: **Прочитайте. Спишите, расставляя, где нужно, запятые.** Здесь неполное придаточное предложение обособлено внутри деепричастного оборота. Это наиболее оптимальное решение.

Но оборот "где нужно" **можно отнести к цельным оборотам,** имеющим значение необособленного обстоятельства: где нужно - в нужных местах.

**Выбор варианта** зависит от структуры предложения, от расстановки логических ударений, также он может быть авторским, например:

(1) Заменят полы **где нУжно** ― и снова начнут работать. Она... прошла точно по операторским меткам, с ходу выполнила все режиссерские задачи ― **где нужно** заплАкала, **где нужно** засмеЯлась…

(2) Не для того ли, чтобы, подбрОсив их, **где нУжно**, направить следствие по ложному пути?

Если оборот не обособляется, то он в **качестве цельной единицы является обстоятельством.**

Если это **обособленное придаточное предложение**, то оно неполное: Спишите, расставляя, где нужно (расставить), запятые. Это безличное предложение, состоящее из сказуемого и союзного слова "где" в роли обстоятельства.

Comment: если это обособленное придаточное предложение внутри деепричастного оборота, то подчеркивать его вместе со всем деепричастным оборотом не нужно? Дееприч. оборотом будет только 'расставляя запятые'?

Comment: Да,  придаточное предложение является вставкой внутри деепричастного оборота и к нему не относится.

Answer (score 2):

> *Спишите, расставляя() где нужно() знаки препинания.*

Запятые на месте скобок нужны для выделения придаточного ***где нужно.***

[**См. у Розенталя:**](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/50.htm)

> **§ 114...** Фразеологические обороты не образуют придаточного предложения и, как правило, эквивалентны члену предложения. Так, в
>   сочетании ***говорит об этом где только может*** последние слова имеют
>   значение **«везде».** Если же какое-либо из приведенных выше и
>   аналогичных сочетаний употреблено не в качестве фразеологического
>   оборота, то оно может образовать придаточное предложение (часто
>   неполное) и выделяться запятыми.
>
> Ср.: *Просторечные слова стали употреблять **где нужно и где не
>   нужно*** (т.е. везде). – *Поставить, **где нужно**, недостающие знаки
>   препинания* (т.е. *там, где нужно*).

Comment: получается, придаточное находится в середине деепричастного оборота? Оно входит в него или разбирается отдельно? Тогда "нужно" - это сказуемое, а "где" - подлежащее (обстоятельство)?